# Kotlin Lambda is Null After StartActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I have two activities, `Activity1` and `Activity2`.

**Activity1.kt**

```
class Activity1: AppCompatActivity {
   private val activity2 = Activity2()

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       activity2.testLambda = {
            println("Should be called" + it)
        }
  }
}
```

**Activity2.kt**

```
class Activity2: AppCompatActivity {
   var testLambda: ((String) -> Unit)? = null

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        testLambda?.invoke("Hello")
   }

}
```

`activity2` was popup by pressing a button in `Activity1`:

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

For some reason, in `Activity2`, `onCreate`, the `testLambda` is `null`. Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android a class that extends `AppCompatActivity`, `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` or anything similar, these classes have different life cycle than typical usual classes and you can't just instantiate them like

```
private val activity2 = Activity2()
```

You have to use intents for instantiating such activities. [more info here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#kotlin)

Moreover to keep it simple for you, **At one time only one activity can be in resumed state** and can be interacted with. So you can't have two activities side by side in a live state and pass data around.

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you are trying to do but that depends on what exactly you want. explain your use-case and I will update the answer more specific answer but here are more broad approaches you can use.

1) [Passing data through intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

2) [Use of a `singleton` i.e Kotlin `object` classes](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/object-singleton)

3) Shared ViewModels using dependency injection (this is much more complicated so I wouldn't advise this if you are a beginner)

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I'm a beginner but just know about Koin for DI. I will try it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

but... it is null

```
var testLambda: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
```

opening `Activity` by `Intent` will create new instance with new `testLambda`

```
val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

`testLambda` isn't static field, so it will be null...

also: don't never ever create `Activity` by just calling `new Activity`/constructor or any other "usual" language way (like you do in `Activity1`). use `Intent` always, pass data through `Bundle`